# Using List<T> In a SubSonic Select Statement?

Tags: subsonic

I was just wondering if you can do something like this

```
List<string> maincolumns = new List<string>();
Select s = new Select(maincolumns)
```

I know I can use a string[] but I need to build up the query and once I set the string[] I can't append columns :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```
List<string> maincolumns = new List<string>();
// example appends...
maincolumns.Add("Column1");
maincolumns.Add("Column2");
Select s = new Select(maincolumns.ToArray());
```